# How to overlay a color onto a Canvas and also add an exlusion region in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

So, simple question I'm sure for you more experienced WPF folk, but I have a simple task (in WinForms) that I am having a bit of trouble implementing in WPF.  When I encounter something like this in WPF it usually just means there's a feature I don't know about, but I couldn't find any examples.  Here's the issue:

Imagine a canvas which displays an image.  Atop this image I have a re-sizable rectangle that can be manipulated by the user.  I want all of the area outside of this rectangle to be masked with a semi-transparent color.  In WinForms I would have simply overriden OnPaint, added an exclusion region to my Graphics object, and then filled the Graphics object with my semi-transparent color.

So, my first inclination was to override OnRender for my Canvas and do it the same way using a DrawingContext.  So, I tried this as a test:

```
protected override void OnRender( DrawingContext dc )
{
    base.OnRender( dc );
    var clipRect = new Rect( 128, 128, 1024, 462 );
    dc.PushClip( new RectangleGeometry( clipRect ) );
    var bounds = new Rect( 0, 0, this.ActualHeight, this.ActualWidth );
    dc.DrawRectangle( new SolidColorBrush( Colors.White.ApplyAlpha( 128 ) ), null, bounds );
}
```

No dice; OnRender never actually fires.

In my experience with WPF (with most things actually) I have realized that, when something which seems as though it should be simple is actually difficult, I'm doing it wrong.  So, any advice on how to set a mask color with a clip region?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use an opacitymask with an excluded region like so:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Canvastest"
    x:Class="Canvastest.MainWindow"
    x:Name="Window"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="640" Height="480">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Canvas Margin="8">
            <Image x:Name="image" Height="410" Width="592" Source="Koala.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="#FD9D5C5C" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=image}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=image}" Name="rect">
                <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                    <DrawingBrush Stretch="None">
                        <DrawingBrush.Drawing>                                                      
                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="#99ffffff">
                                <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                    <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Exclude">
                                        <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                                            <RectangleGeometry>
                                                <RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{local:RectConverter}">
                                                        <Binding Path="(Canvas.Left)" ElementName="image"/>
                                                        <Binding Path="(Canvas.Top)" ElementName="image"/>
                                                        <Binding Path="Width" ElementName="rect"/>
                                                        <Binding Path="Height" ElementName="rect"/>
                                                    </MultiBinding>
                                                </RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                                            </RectangleGeometry>
                                        </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                                        <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                                            <RectangleGeometry>
                                                <RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{local:RectConverter}">
                                                        <Binding Path="(Canvas.Left)" ElementName="thumb"/>
                                                        <Binding Path="(Canvas.Top)" ElementName="thumb"/>
                                                        <Binding Path="Width" ElementName="thumb"/>
                                                        <Binding Path="Height" ElementName="thumb"/>
                                                    </MultiBinding>
                                                </RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                                            </RectangleGeometry>
                                        </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>                                       
                                    </CombinedGeometry>                                 
                                </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>                             
                            </GeometryDrawing>
                        </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                    </DrawingBrush>
                </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
            </Rectangle>
            <Thumb Name="thumb" DragDelta="Thumb_DragDelta" Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent" Cursor="SizeAll" Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="50">
                <Thumb.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Thumb">
                        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                                    <Grid Background="Transparent">

                                    </Grid>                                    
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </Thumb.Style>
            </Thumb>
            <Grid Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=thumb}" Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=thumb}" Canvas.Left="{Binding (Canvas.Left), ElementName=thumb}" Canvas.Top="{Binding (Canvas.Top), ElementName=thumb}">
                <Thumb Width="5" Height="5" Cursor="SizeNWSE" DragDelta="Thumb_DragDelta_1" Background="Transparent" Margin="0,0,-5,-5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
            </Grid>

        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

with codebehind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Thumb_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            var thumb = sender as Thumb;
            var left = (double)thumb.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty);
            var top = (double)thumb.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty);

            if (double.IsNaN(left))
                left = 0.0;
            if (double.IsNaN(top))
                top = 0.0;
            left += e.HorizontalChange;
            top += e.VerticalChange;
            thumb.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty,left);
            thumb.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, top);
        }

        private void Thumb_DragDelta_1(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
        {            
            thumb.Width += e.HorizontalChange;
            thumb.Height += e.VerticalChange;
        }
    }

    public class RectConverter : MarkupExtension,IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (values == null || values.Length != 4 || values.OfType<double>().Count() != 4) return new Rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
            for (var i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                if (double.IsNaN((double)values[i]))
                    values[i] = 0.0;
            return new Rect((double)values[0], (double)values[1], (double)values[2], (double)values[3]);
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return new RectConverter();
        }
    }
```

EDIT: had a little more fun with this to code a complete example

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for providing such a complete example.  I'm having a bit of trouble getting the rect to show up, but it's probably something I'm doing wrong.  I'm going to try it in a clean test project to remove some variables, but if it works I'll mark this as accepted.  Thanks again!

Comment: Apparently this is one task that is much easier in WinForms =D

Comment: @Ed you really think so? I don't have too much knowledge of Controls in Winforms, but I'd think using the Thumb elements in WPF (like I did - or preferably a little cleaner) is so much easier than handling the user input in Winforms

Comment: Oh yeah, user input is much easier, it's this particular problem that is more complex in WPF (only 2 lines of code in WinForms).  Like I said, I'm likely just missing something simple.  I will get some time to play around with it later tonight.